# Error in function to normalize data applied to a data frame

Tags: r, function, normalization

I have downloaded the bike-sharing-dataset from the UCI Machine learning repository and am trying to implement a multivariate linear regression in R. Here is the format of the data:

```
> head(data1)
  season mnth hr holiday weekday workingday weathersit temp  atemp  hum windspeed cnt
1      1    1  0       0       6          0          1 0.24 0.2879 0.81    0.0000  16
2      1    1  1       0       6          0          1 0.22 0.2727 0.80    0.0000  40
3      1    1  2       0       6          0          1 0.22 0.2727 0.80    0.0000  32
4      1    1  3       0       6          0          1 0.24 0.2879 0.75    0.0000  13
5      1    1  4       0       6          0          1 0.24 0.2879 0.75    0.0000   1
6      1    1  5       0       6          0          2 0.24 0.2576 0.75    0.0896   1
```

I am trying to normalize specific columns (that have not already been normalized) with the following function:

```
normalize <- function(x) {
  return ((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)))
}
```

The problem is that when I run:

```
 dfNorm <- as.data.frame(lapply(data1["season", "mnth", "hr", "weekday", "weathersit"], normalize))
```

I get the following error:

> Error in `[.data.frame`(data1, "season", "month", "hour", "weekday",
>   "weathersit") :    unused arguments ("weekday", "weathersit")

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: I think the column names need to be in a vector: `data1[c("season", "month", "hour", "weekday", "weathersit")]`. Also, unrelated to the error: you used `mnth, hr` in your first example but `month, hour` in the second.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! The only problem is that the new df contains only the normalized columns. How can I modify the specific columns and leave them in-place in the original df?

Comment: Either `cbind` or `merge` the original.

Comment: @Parfait can you explain in further detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify in-place, I'd use `dplyr::mutate`. Something like this should work:

```
library(dplyr)
dfNorm <- data1 %>% 
  mutate_at(.vars = vars(season, mnth, hr, weekday, weathersit),
            .funs = funs(normalize))
```

Comment: Thank you, however, I am trying to do this without the use of any R packages or libraries- is it possible to edit your answer to account for this?

Comment: As @Parfait says, you could `cbind` or `merge` the required columns together. But that's messy, when there's a way to do it in-place. Trust me, learn `dplyr`, it will make your life with data frames much more productive and fun.

Answer (score 1):

Simply assign the `lapply` to new columns:

```
df[c("season_norm", "mnth_norm", "hr_norm", "weekday_norm", "weathersit_norm")] <-
   lapply(df[c("season", "mnth", "hr", "weekday", "weathersit")], normalize)
```